# NameError when running script QGIS Python 3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to run a script that loops through a series of point layers and interpolates using the TIN interpollation method using python on QGIS.  The script worked in the past, but now it fails with the following error:

NameError: name 'QgsProcessingFeedback' is not defined

```
import qgis.analysis
import qgis.core
import processing
import os
import fnmatch
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback #added based on [post 194737][1]

use_cols = [6,9,10,11]
col_names = ["Depth","Velocity","Froude","Stress"]
source_geopackage = "D:/GIS/TRF2/PC3_hydropts.gpkg"
interim_path = "D:/GIS/TRF2/Raster_output/"
export_path = "D:/GIS/TRF2/PC3_rasters/"
layers = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers() #using canvas layers
for layer in layers:
layerType = layer.type()
if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
    for i in range(0,len(use_cols)):
        col = use_cols[i]
        output_file_name = layer.name()+"_"+col_names[i]
        export_file_name = interim_path + output_file_name+".tif"
        vlayer = source_geopackage+"|layername="+layer.name()+"::~::0::~::"+str(col)+"::~::0"
        processing.run("qgis:tininterpolation", {
        'INTERPOLATION_DATA':vlayer,
        'METHOD':0,'COLUMNS':2487,'ROWS':929,
        'EXTENT':'1793310.0,1801470.0,498942.0,501991.0 [EPSG:2285]',
        'OUTPUT': export_file_name})
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)
>     File "", line 13, in 
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 84, in run
>       return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 119, in runAlgorithm
>       feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
>   NameError: name 'QgsProcessingFeedback' is not defined

I'm running QGIS v3.0.2 on Windows, and accessing Python through the QGIS console.

When I wrote the loop, I ran TIN interpolation through the processing framework and copied the settings from the history.  I tried to repeat that process, but I get the same error.  The algorithm runs fine through processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()` as a parameter for `processing.run()`:

```
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback() # I'd put this out of any for loops

processing.run("qgis:tininterpolation", {
        'INTERPOLATION_DATA':vlayer,
        'METHOD':0,'COLUMNS':2487,'ROWS':929,
        'EXTENT':'1793310.0,1801470.0,498942.0,501991.0 [EPSG:2285]',
        'OUTPUT': export_file_name
    },
    feedback=feedback)
```

Comment: What is this line doing?  It worked smoothly, and there was another place later in the script where I needed to add it again.  Any idea why the script ran fine a month ago (with a different set of files) but fails now?

Comment: Yeah, that `feedback` parameter became mandatory for a while, don't know why. But testing against current dev version such parameter seems to be optional again.